# Adaptive/reactive background music in SpriteKit?

Tags: dynamic, avfoundation, sprite-kit, background-music

Wondering what the best approach is for mixing tracks based on gameplay as well as adding or removing tracks from the loop on the fly based on game conditions.

Simply speaking let's say we had an audio file track for each boolean in a set. The music loops with each individual track being muted or unmuted based on the changing booleans which are attached to game events.

One might be, player speed increases above a certain value and thus a drum track is added to the loop.

Should I be able to achieve this with Apple's stuff like SpriteKit or AVFoundation or should I be looking into some more advanced libraries?

Comment: This may be prohibitive on the CPU. iOS devices can only decode one MP3 (streaming music) file, additional music needs to be decoded by the CPU. CPU is even more taxed by mixing channels. If you use uncompressed audio (caf, wav) you're going to have them buffered into memory, which means possibly large amounts of memory. Unless you're creating an app where this is the central and key feature of the app it is probably not worth looking into based on the technical difficulties to implement this feature (I just scratched the surface, making it sound 'right' is another problem altogether).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for the feedback, I have been poking around the docs for [the amazing audio engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/), I'm not very familiar with the terms but it looks like I should be able to manipulate multiple channels using this, just have to see if it plays nice with SpriteKit

Comment: @ioSamurai keep us updated on this!